Run extension command from OpenVSCode
I am using the vscode-ibmi extension to work with IBMi systems and edit source code inside OpenVSCode Server.
vscode-ibmi has recently introduced a new feature to open connect automatically to IBMi and open a file from URL. This feature works only with a local "VS Code" because it uses the following syntax:
vscode://halcyontechltd.code-for-ibmi/open?host=1.1.1.1&path=/home/liama/xyz
This will send a request to the "halcyontechltd.code-for-ibmi" extension, to run the "open" action on host "1.1.1.1" to open file "/home/liama/xyz"
I would like to do the same thing with OpenVSCode Server.
For example, if my OpenVSCode Server URL is:
https://myserver.smeup.com:3500/ 
The syntax to open a file with vscode-ibmi should be something like this (I just invented it to show to concept):
https://myserver.smeup.com:3500/vscode://halcyontechltd.code-for-ibmi/open?host=1.1.1.1&path=/home/liama/xyz
Obviously this link wouldn't work.
Is it possible to use the "vscode://" in the URL with "OpenVSCode" so that I can run the vscode-ibmi open command?
What is the right URL syntax?
